# lightweight unit testing in python

Tags: python, racket

I'm considering using Python to teach introductory programming, and I'm looking for a lightweight unit testing framework.  I've taken a look at unittest, and--as far as I can tell--it looks insanely *non*-lightweight.

For example, here's what I'd like to be able to write:

```
import unittest

def f(x):
  return x+2

checkEqual(f(3),5)
```

... and *nothing else*. To show you where I'm coming from, this is what I'd write in Racket's beginning student language:

```
(define (f x)
  (+ x 2))

(check-expect (f 3) 5)
```

... and that's it.  Surely someone's written this tool, and I'm just not finding it?

(Apologies in advance for any appearance of flame-baiting. This is a serious question.)

SELF-EDIT:

Before anyone points this out: yes, I could write def checkEqual(a,b): print(a==b) ; I'm looking for something with a bit more: it should be able to check numbers with tolerances, it should have support for printing only failed test cases, it should be able to tell you how many test cases failed.  Again, I'm confident that this code can be written; I'm just trying to avoid re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: I think you meant to write: `from unittest import checkEqual`

Comment: On my machine, that just signals an error: "ImportError: cannot import name checkEqual".

Comment: On my machine, if I `import unittest`... `NameError: name 'checkEqual' is not defined`

Comment: Right... neither one works. As I wrote, "I'd *like* to be able to write..." (emphasis added). Thus the answers below!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doctests are a wonderful suggestion, but if you want to get close to your example code I would suggest py.test (pytest.org). Your example would be written something like:

```
def f(x):
    return x+2

def test_equal():       # py.test looks for functions that start with test_
    assert f(3) == 5
```

if I put that in a file called tt.py and run it with py.test, it looks like this:

```
w:\tmp>py.test tt.py
============================= test session starts =============================
platform win32 -- Python 2.6.6 -- pytest-2.2.3
collected 1 items

tt.py .

========================== 1 passed in 0.01 seconds ===========================
```

if I change the assert to f(3) == 6, and run it again I get:

```
w:\tmp>py.test tt.py
============================= test session starts =============================
platform win32 -- Python 2.6.6 -- pytest-2.2.3
collected 1 items

tt.py F

================================== FAILURES ===================================
_________________________________ test_equal __________________________________

    def test_equal():       # py.test looks for functions that start with test_
>       assert f(3) == 6
E       assert 5 == 6
E        +  where 5 = f(3)

tt.py:5: AssertionError
========================== 1 failed in 0.01 seconds ===========================
```

py.test also scales up, and you can have it run coverage, distribute tests over multiple CPUs etc.  It also finds and runs unittest test and can also run doctests.

Comment: This looks like the best thing out there. I'm not totally in love with the reflection-flavored "functions-starting-with-test_", but aside from that it looks like a nice solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend [Doctest](http://docs.python.org/library/doctest.html).

Your example would look like:

```
def f(x):
    """
    >>> f(3)
    5
    """
    return x + 2
```

Why?:

1. It's super simple: "when I run this thing I should get this answer back"
2. It works on the function level - which might allow you to introduce testing even before classes
3. Mirrors the interactive Python experience.

Comment: Ouch! Forgive my non-value-neutral wording, but from where I'm sitting, that looks ... um ... let's just say, very, very, non-optimal. Anything based on parsing of strings is likely to be extremely fragile. I can see about thirteen things going wrong here. Very not nice. I'm really biting my tongue, here.

Comment: @JohnClements Doctest is not the most robust unit testing framework, obviously, but screwing up strings isn't a huge problem since the idea is that you past into the doc string the exact input and output from the interpreter. I don't think it's right for your situation, mostly because it works better for simple regression testing than anything else and I'm assuming you want to teach in a more TDD style. Don't bash the framework though, it's a very simple way to make sure things are working on small projects.

Answer (score 2):

Two common alternatives are [*nose*](https://github.com/nose-devs/nose) and [*py.test*](http://pytest.org/latest/).  They both have a very lightweight syntax, but are also full-featured.

Here's an extended introduction to nose:  http://ivory.idyll.org/articles/nose-intro.html

And here is a sample function and test using py.test:

```
# content of test_sample.py
def func(x):
    return x + 1

def test_answer():
    assert func(3) == 5
```

Run the test from the command-line:

```
$ py.test
=========================== test session starts ============================
platform darwin -- Python 2.7.1 -- pytest-2.2.2
collecting ... collected 1 items

test_sample.py F

================================= FAILURES =================================
_______________________________ test_answer ________________________________

    def test_answer():
>       assert func(3) == 5
E       assert 4 == 5
E        +  where 4 = func(3)

test_sample.py:5: AssertionError
========================= 1 failed in 0.02 seconds =========================
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import unittest

def f(x):
    return x + 2

class TestFunctionF(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_f(self):
        self.assertEqual(f(3), 5)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Produces:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s
OK
```

Comment: Blecch! Can you imagine telling a student on the first day to type all of that goop?

Comment: Why, yes. Yes, I _can_ imagine it. OK, maybe the second day :)

Comment: Thanks for your good-humored response! I'm glad I didn't just make you angry. :)